# Using AWS CLI to query across all aws services but only those filtered by specific tag value

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, tags

I want to query my whole account against all objects' tags and find those with a specific value in one of my tags.
I'm using both OSX and Windows, I think the syntax is almost the same anyways.
Can this be achieved with one line? As the AWS CLI has commands and for each command subcommands for "describe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a [Resource Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/what-are-resource-groups.html) in the Management Console, which gives a view of resources with specific tags.

Otherwise, you can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to call the many `describe-*` commands with `--filter` parameters based on tags. (Tip: See the [JMESPATH tutorial](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) to master filter definitions.

Comment: Thank you for the intel, i will definitely check it